# Find child of parent container using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am probably looking at this the wrong way, but I am having trouble locating an element within my page and am hoping someone can help.

The scenario is this: 
I have a `<ul>` containing a number of `<li>'s` which in turn contain `<a href>'s`. I am getting the value of the rel attribute of the clicked `<a href>` and want to replace the text in a `<span class='someclass'>` which is located in a parent container.  There may be more than one of these `<span class='someclass'>` on the page so I need to find the closest one.

Here is how my HTML looks

```
<h3 class="my-header-class">
   <span class="some-class">Title Text</span>
 </h3>
 <ul class="tabs">
   <li><a rel="Title Text 1" href="#tab1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a rel="Title Text 2" href="#tab2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a rel="Title Text 3" href="#tab3">Link 3</a></li> 
 </ul>
```

Here is my javascript

```
 var titletext = $(this).attr('rel');
 var container = $(this).parent().children(".some-class");      
 container.text(titletext);
```

The titletext variable is being set with the correct text but I am unable to replace the text of the `<span class='someclass'>`. I assume because I am not finding it correctly.

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: try to edit your question correctly to get answers, it was unreadable (all html tags were stripped)

Comment: @manji: It looks fine to me..?

Comment: because I edited your question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().parent().prev().children(".some-class");


 <h3>     <!-- PREV OF UL -->
  <span>  <!-- CHILDREN OF H3 -->

 <ul>     <!-- PARENT OF <LI> AND <A> -->
  <li>    <!-- PARENT OF <A> AND CHILDREN OF <UL> -->
   <a>    <!-- CHILDREN OF <UL> AND <LI> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent().prev('h3').children(".some-class")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
    var titletext = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).closest("ul.tabs").prev().find(".some-class").text(titletext);
});
```

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/67vTV/